# Issue with importing titles (dbmovies api)

Tags: wordpress, api, server, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Was wondering if someone could help me with an issue.
I have a wordpress, with the theme ''Dooplay''.
Inside the theme it has an importer which it pulls movie data ect from dbmovies (dbmvs.com)
Its importing movies ect still but when i go back onto its allowing me too import the same content when usually i shouldnt be able too,, and because not known whats imported im ending up with loads of duplicates of movies now on the site...I disabled cloudflare but still didnt work...Its also not showing me stats of my api key on the dash ,,just all says zero....but log onto the dbmovies site and it shows stats..Not sure whats going on here ?
Anyone have any idea why this issue could be happening.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Apk.png)

Comment: Ive put the theme on a temporary website,,,and the importer works on that, so its isolated too my site

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.